# WebView removeJavascriptInterface() method below API 11

Tags: android, android-webview

My app support API level 7 onwards. I am using removeJavascriptInterface() method to remove the JavascriptInterface bridge but this method does not exists for API < 11. 
 Is there any way to remove JavascriptInterface below API 11 ?

Comment: Yust set a new fake interface. Or null? Please try.

Comment: @greenapps: I am using `mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(myJavaScriptInterface,"ABC");` to add the bridge. Can you explain how to make it null ?  I have tried the following: `mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(myJavaScriptInterface,null);` but it closes my app when any call from Javascript such as ABC.interfaceMethod(params); is fired.

Comment: If with a fake interface try `mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(myFakeJavaScriptInterface,"fake")`. If with a null interface then try `mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(null, "")`; But maybe the 'add' is to be taken serious. Maybe more interfaces are possible. I don't know. Just test it out.

Comment: By adding interface with new object "fake" it does not solve my concern as html page can now use `fake.interfaceMethod(params);` call. Also, multiple interfaces for a WebView are possible so `mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(null, "");` doesn't affect the "ABC" interface. Is there no alternative of removeJavascriptInterface() ?

Comment: First I do not understand that 'html page' would ever use the fake interface. Second you could change myJavaScriptInterface to react different or not react at all. Just add a boolean to indicate what to do.

Comment: OK let me tell you, my app displays search results which may/may not be trusted. Now, when I add a javascriptInterface any untrusted 'html page' may exploit the vulnerability caused due to this. So for minimizing(can't confirm it completely avoids) this vulnerability, I am removing the interface which works fine for Android versions > 2.3.4 (API 10) and untrusted 'html page' couldn't call inherited Android methods. Also, I am aware of @JavascriptInterface annotation but it only exists from Android 4.2 onwards.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57405/discussion-between-r-bhardwaj-and-greenapps).

Comment: Was there a resolution here?